# Event problem C# .NET UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, events, updatepanel, user-controls

I have an UpdatePanel and in it a regular Panel. In the Panel I dynamically add simple UserControls. The Usercontrol has a Button and a Label. When I click on a button in a control it removes all controls in the Panel which I have added dynamically.
Can anyone help?

```
    int controlID = 0;
    List<Control> cc = new List<Control>();
    if (Session["ControlsCompleted"] != null)
    {
        cc = Session["ControlsCompleted"] as List<Control>;
        for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        {
            pnlCompletedEducation.Controls.Add(cc[i]);
        }
        controlID = cc.Count;
    }
    Controls_TestWebUserControl ct = LoadControl(@"Controls\TestWebUserControl.ascx") as Controls_TestWebUserControl;
    ct.ID = controlID.ToString();
    cc.Add(ct);
    ct.EnableViewState = true;
    pnlCompletedEducation.Controls.Add(ct);
    txtInstitutionName.Text = controlID.ToString();
    List<Control> lc = new List<Control>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pnlCompletedEducation.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        lc.Add(pnlCompletedEducation.Controls[i]);
    }
    Session["ControlsCompleted"] = lc;
```

This is how I add the controls to the panel. I had to keep them somewhere, and i couldn't do it with the ViewState, so i used a Session, which is a bad idea.

Comment: You should post the code both for where you're adding the controls and the event handler for the button's Click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you are adding the user control dynamically. Are you having code like this:

```
void Page_Load(...)    
{
     if (!IsPostback)
        // AddUserControl here.
}
```

You need to add the user control during every request, also postbacks, because it will not be stored in the view state that you have modified the control tree.

Answer (score 0):

You problem that you have not recreated (for example at Page_Load) dynamically added control.
Make sure that control is recreated on IsPostBack